# To get a part of a string using batch scripting while in loop

Tags: batch-file

My folder contain 5 sub folders: 
folder1_w,
folder2,
folder3_w,
folder4,
folder5.

I have to find out folders with name ending with "_w"

i tried this

```
@echo off

for /D %%i in (*) do (
    set name=%%i
    if %name:~-2% == _W ( 
        echo pass
    ) else (
        echo fail
    )   
)

pause
```

Comment: Edit your question and add what did you have tried until now as code !

Comment: you could just do `for /d %%i in (*_w) do echo %%i` hopefully "someone" does not complain that `for` loops are over complicating this.

Comment: thank you _/\_  Gerhard

Comment: Your script lacks of [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), which is required when you write and read a variable in the same block of code. Though just using the pattern `*_w` instead of `*` would return only folders whose names end in `_w` without need of a variable and `if` conditions...

Comment: @Gerhard, please post that comment as an answer, to hopefully prevent the question from being closed as a delayed expansion duplicate. Thank you.